# How can I use a green screen to add a video onto a moving plane?

Tags: video, tracking, compositing-nodes

So, I've been working on my project for a little bit now.
I'll be holding some boards, and flip through them whilst superimposing videos on them.

I've grasped Plane Tracking, and how to project (superimpose) a video onto it!

But now I hear that using a green screen (as the plane) will be much easier later on, especially when it comes to masking out obstructions (such as fingers holding the screen).

I can manage that. I can get a nice green (or whatever other color) panel and hold it up to the camera.

So, I've gone up to the "Tracking" and "Creating a Plane Track" stage; I've finished those.

But, I can't find many tutorials telling me what to do afterwards!

I did find one, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGSKjFz4NVg), but it's an older version of Blender and some parts are a bit confusing.

Could someone point me to a tutorial that's updated, so I can simply follow along to achieve this simple effect?

I apologize again for the questions; The deadline is tight on this project and I only need to know how to do about 2 effects, nothing more.. I can do the rest in After Effects, which I actually know how to handle. Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use afterFX for this.

The idea is quite simple.
You use green, or some color that is not present in the scene, to create a matte (or mask) that can be used to combine other elements in the scene.

In the compositor connect the image that has the green element add a keying node, select the key color and the node will output Image and Matte separately.

Use the Matte to control the mix between the tracked plane and the image.

[image]

Or use just use the mask and feed the original image. This setup will avoid correlated alpha issues.

[image]